# Next Js modal close on Scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a Modal in My Next.JS app, and I added a feature to close the modal when the user starts to scroll outside the modal. But the effect is applying inside the modal as well. How can I close only when scrolled outside but not inside?

```
function HomeFilterModal({ visible, onClose }) {
  const toggle = useSelector(selectModal);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleOnClose = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === "container") onClose();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 10) {
        onClose();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);
  if (!visible) return null;

  return (
    <div
      id="container"
      onClick={handleOnClose}
      className="fixed top-24 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 bg-black bg-opacity-30 backdrop-blur-sm h-screen z-50 hidden sm:flex justify-center "
    >
      <div
        id="nonscroll"
        className=" h-[28rem] w-2/3 bg-[#fafaf9] drop-shadow-md rounded-3xl flex flex-col items-center overflow-hidden overflow-y-scroll scrollbar-none snap-y
        "
      >
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full px-4 py-4 border-b">
          <div
            onClick={() => dispatch(setModal(!toggle))}
            className=" rounded-full border h-8 w-8 border-gray-600 hover grid place-items-center hover:border-0 hover:drop-shadow-2xl hover:shadow-black"
          >
            <XMarkIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
          </div>
          <p className="text-2xl tracking-wider">Filter</p>

          <p
            onClick={() => dispatch(resetFunc())}
            className="text-sm hover:underline pr-2 cursor-pointer"
          >
            Clear All
          </p>
        </div>

        <HomePriceFilter />
        <HomeLocationFilter />
        <HomeTypeFilter />
        {/* <div className="py-6 h-48 bg-white w-full text-transparent">hey</div> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeFilterModal;
```

Answer (score -1):

you could make use of the `Intersection Observer API`. Very powerful and fast:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

just assuming, because I didn't deep dive in your code.

Creating an observer (as the docs states):

```
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Observe your parent view (the background):

```
let target = document.querySelector('#yourParentSelector');
observer.observe(target);
```

Trigger your `close()` only if observed (background) moves.

Comment: how can i make use of it in my case

Comment: it didn't work for the scroll.